# How to pass Android Jenkins build timestamp to s3 for webpage rendering?

Tags: android, build, jenkins, amazon-s3

I am using Jenkins to test, build and release an Android project. Jenkins puts the generated .apk file into an s3 bucket like so:

```
s3cmd put example_app/bin/example_app.apk s3://preview.example.com/android/example.apk;
s3cmd setacl --acl-public s3://preview.example.com/android/example.apk;
```

The .apk in this bucket can then be accessed and downloaded by the public when visiting preview.example.com

The issue I am running into is that I also want to pass along the timestamp of when Jenkins built the example_app android project so that this time/date can be displayed on the preview.example.com page as well. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it does not seem ideal...

Jenkins has an environment variable called BUILD_ID which is:
*The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss)*

In the Jenkins build I created a text file to contain this date string and put it in an s3 bucket:

```
touch timestamp.txt
echo ${BUILD_ID} > timestamp.txt
s3cmd put ./timestamp.txt s3://preview.example.com/android/timestamp.txt;
s3cmd setacl --acl-public s3://preview.example.com/android/timestamp.txt;
```

Then when rendering the webpage I use ajax to access, manipulate and display this date like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://preview.example.com/android/timestamp.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      var timestamp = data.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/," $2-$3-$1 $4:$5:$6");
      $("div.timestamp-unstable-android").append("Updated: "+timestamp);
    }
  });
```

Which displays a date that looks like this: Updated: **07-10-2014 17:29:38**

So this works... however there is still the problem that this is UTC time, not local